# RecyclerView with 3 by 3 item Horizontal scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, pagersnaphelper

In my project, I need to show the list of item in 3 by 3 on the horizontal scroll view with left and right arrow. If I click on the right arrow next 3 item should display like below image

[image]

I am confused that I need to go with ViewPager or RecyclerView with SnapHelper or PagerSnapHelper. Is there any other suggestions on how I can achieve it

Comment: Basically, you're asking for opinions on which component to use in this situation?

Comment: Yes which is best option to use or any other components i can use for this situation

Answer (score 2):

For answer this qustion you should use viewpager and in any page use recycler and sending data 3 by 3 in page and set data to recycler.

1. The first Step you should add Viewpager in parent xml :
   activity_main.xml

   ```
   <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/left_arrow"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view_pager"
           android:rotation="180"
           android:padding="8dp"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view_pager"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"/>

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/view_pager"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right_arrow"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_arrow"
           android:layout_height="150dp"/>

   <com.rd.PageIndicatorView
           android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/view_pager"
           app:piv_animationType="worm"
           app:piv_dynamicCount="true"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           app:piv_interactiveAnimation="true"
           app:piv_radius="3dp"
           app:piv_unselectedColor="#999999"
           app:piv_selectedColor="#000000"
           app:piv_viewPager="@id/view_pager"
           attrs:piv_padding="8dp" />
   <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/right_arrow"
           android:padding="8dp"
           android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view_pager"
           android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view_pager"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"/>
   ```
2. In this step you should create Viewpager adapter :
   pageAdapter.kt

   ```
   override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
       val firstItem = ((position + 1) * 3) - 2
       val lastItem = ((position + 1) * 3)
       val itemSet = arrayListOf<String>()
       for (i in firstItem..lastItem) {
           if (i <= items.size)
               itemSet.add(items[i - 1])
       }
       return ItemFragment.newInstance(itemSet)
   }

   override fun getCount(): Int {
       return size
   }
   ```
3. In the third step, you should create a fragment to show each page of viewPager and just in Oncreate set recycler adapter and send data to adapter :
   ItemFragment

   ```
   // Creates the view controlled by the fragment
   val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, container, false)
   val recycler = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler)

   // Retrieve and display the movie data from the Bundle
   val args = arguments
   recycler.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity,3)
   recycler.adapter = ItemAdapter(args?.getStringArrayList("items")!!, this.activity!!)
   ```
4. And The Last Just create RecyclerAdapter and show data to each item in list:
   ItemAdapter.kt

   ```
   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
       return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false))
   }

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
       holder?.title?.text = items.get(position)
   }

   override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return items.size
   }
   ```

   **Result :**
   [image]

**if you want to see the full source, just go to this [link](https://github.com/hassannaghibi/RecyclerView-with-3-by-3-item-Horizontal-scroll-with-Kotlin)**

Answer (score 0):

What about scroll through smoothScrollToPosition?
Something like this

```
int offset = 3;
int size = objectsList.size()-1;
@OnClick{
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(offset);
if((offset+3)<size) {
   offset = offset + 3;
} else 
    offset = size;
}
```